# Can't require gem in IRB console using jruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby, irb

I'm using jRuby at the moment (version 1.6.5) on my local machine.

```
rvm use jruby
```

If I do a

```
which cucumber
```

I get /Users/sebastiano/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/bin/cucumber

but when I open up the Ruby console (irb) and I try requiring 'cucumber'

```
require 'cucumber'
```

I get:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- cucumber
```

Any clue on that? I can see the gem installed in '/Users/sebastiano/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I got it. I had to do `require 'rubygems'` as the first instruction.

Comment: because you use jruby normaly without --1.9 flag option. In 1.9 mode you don't have to.